# Integration testing new records with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am testing creation of projects (with rspec integration test) and am wondering why test wont find the project i just told it to create... here's my code

```
  1 require 'spec_helper'
  2 
  3 describe "Projects" do
  4   describe "create project" do
  5 
  6     before :each do
  8       @valid_project = { :name => 'Myproject', :description => 'project description' }
  9     end
 10 
 11     it "should create and redirect to a new project" do
 12       lambda do
 13         visit root_path
 14         click_link 'new project'        
 15         fill_in :name, :with => @valid_project[:name]
 16         fill_in :description, :with => @valid_project[:description] 
 17         click_button 'Create'
 18         current_path.should == project_path(Project.find_by_name!(@valid_project[:name]))
 19         page.should have_content 'Project has been created'
 20 
 21         #in adition, all these don't work and I don't know why...
 22 
 23         #response.should render_template :new
 24         #page.should have_content 'Myproject'
 25         #response.should have_selector('h1', :content => 'Myproject')
 26 
 27       end.should change(Project, :count).by(1)
 28     end
 29   end
 30 end
```

This line 18 returns this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Project with name =
>   Myproject

I don't understand why... Also in the comments in the code above are some more tests that don't work, and again, I don't know why... Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this likely means is that the Create button action failed somehow so the record didn't get created.

Try inserting

```
save_and_open_page
```

after

```
click_button 'Create'
```

That will open the page in your browser and show you the current state of the page.

Comment: and btw, when I create the project manually it all goes well, create button creates...

Comment: ok, just found out that this fill_in :name actually fills in :description. why in the world is that happening?

Comment: Can you post the view that this is testing? It looks up fields by name , ID or label.

Comment: the view isn't the problem. after inserting save_and_open_page after each line up there I can see that fill_in :name fills in name, but fill_in :description fills in the :name field instead of :description. why is that happening?

Comment: omg, got the problem... i must use fill_in 'Name' instead of fill_in :name ! you know why is that?

Comment: That is likely because you have a label for that field with the value "Name". The thing is that if the :description field didn't exist, you should have gotten a different error.